# SmtpClient and MailMessage - How to format for anchor tags?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, smtp

I have an application that requires a user confirm their email upon registering, so I've created some functionality to send the user an email, with a link, where they can click on the link and then confirm their email.

In order to do this I'm using both `MailMessage` and `SmtpClient` classes to send the email.

Currently, my code is thus:

```
public ActionResult Send() {
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage {
        Subject = "Confirm Email",
        Body = "<a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a>",
        IsBodyHtml = true
    };

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Send(email);

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Email");
}
```

Now upon researching I found that the `IsBodyHtml` flag will help if I'm trying to send an email that has HTML contained within, although upon testing, the emails I'm receiving are not formatting anchor tags properly.

[image]

Any idea what I may be doing wrong, or how differently I can go about formatting my message body?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried including full HTML start and end tags?

Comment: Isn't that what the `<a>` and `</a>` for?

Comment: code you shared different from the  link you are displaying!!!

Comment: Hello, Delfino. Thanks for asking and for sharing your solution. Would you mind formatting the title as a question then other people can figure out what is the problem? Regards.

Answer (score 0):

So, I made a goof here. Seems that the messages I was trying to send myself were going to Outlook's Junk Mail folder, which strips out the `href` value and displays it in the e-mail.

If I right click on the email and select `Display HTML` then the link displays as expected.

Oops!